# How to access nested widgets properties in Awesome

Tags: lua, lua-table, awesome-wm

I'm trying to access the properties of the following widget:

```lua
local cpu_widget = wibox.widget{
    {
        max_value = 100,
        paddings = 1,
        border_width = 2,
        widget = wibox.widget.progressbar,
    },
    {
        font = beautiful.font_type .. "8",
        widget = wibox.widget.textbox,
    },
    forced_height = 100,
    forced_width  = 20,
    direction     = 'east',
    layout        = wibox.container.rotate,
}
```

I've tried through the conventional way, using `cpu_widget[1].value` or `cpu_widget[2].text`, but that didn't work.

Any thoughts on how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the "Accessing Widgets" on https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/documentation/03-declarative-layout.md.html (I can't seem to link to this section directly)

Basically: You can add `id = "bar"` and `id = "text"` to your widgets and use these identifiers to retrieve the widgets again.

In case Elv13 ever sees this answer: You did great work on the docs!